# Download a serialized file using ajax get request

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I am facing an issue in sending an ajax get request to download a file served by a REST API in java.

The REST api

```
 @GET
 @Path("/{modelName}/export")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
```

The API is working fine. The problem is with my ajax call

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: serverUrl+'/api/models/'+modelName+'/export',
                success : function(res){
                    alert("success");
                    console.log(res);
                },
                error : function(res){
                    alert("error");
                    console.log(res);                
                }
            });
```

When this call is executed I need the file to be downloaded. How do I modify the ajax call in order to that?

i am getting a success alert when I execute it, and some random strings are printed in the console.

Comment: pls see the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ajax when you download file. Becouse anyway file downloads async by browsers.

You can use plain html for this purpouse:

```
<a href="YourPath">Download File</a>
```

But if you want to get file with js you can do it like this:

```
window.location.href = serverUrl+'/api/models/'+modelName+'/export';
```